# Existence of laplacian imply existence of all the terms in its sum?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded and smooth domain.

Is it true that if some function $f\in H^1(\Omega)$ admits in the distributional sense $\Delta f\in L^2(\Omega)$ then there exists $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2},\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}\in L^2(\Omega)$?

By $\Delta f=g\in L^2(\Omega)$ in $\Omega$ in the distributional sense we mean that $$\int_{\Omega} f(x)\Delta \phi(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} g(x)\phi(x)\ dx,\ \forall\ \phi\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$$

My feeling is that this is not true, but I cannot find a counterexample yet.

Comment: My guess is probably not: Something like $z^{-1/2}$ in $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$, viewed as a holomorphic function in the disk or radius 1 and center 1 should be in $H^1$ of that domain, is harmonic there, but the second derivatives blow up too fast at $z=0$.

Comment: Ignore my comment, no power function like that can be in $H^1$.